# Raphael JS Implementing a "Pencil" tool efficiently

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am working on a project that requires end users to be able draw in the browser much like [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) and send SVG data to the server for processing.

I've started playing with the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) framework and it seems promising.

Currently I am trying to implement a pencil or freeline type tool. Basically I am just drawing a new path based on percentage of mouse movement in the drawing area. However, in the end this is going to create massive amount of paths to deal with.

> Is it possible to shorten an SVG path
>   by converting mouse movement to use
>   Curve and Line paths instead of line
>   segments?

Below is draft code I whipped up to do the job ...

```
    // Drawing area size const
   var SVG_WIDTH = 620;
   var SVG_HEIGHT = 420;

   // Compute movement required for new line
   var xMove = Math.round(SVG_WIDTH * .01);
   var yMove = Math.round(SVG_HEIGHT * .01);

   // Min must be 1
   var X_MOVE = xMove ? xMove : 1;
   var Y_MOVE = yMove ? yMove : 1;

   // Coords
   var start, end, coords = null;
   var paperOffset = null;
   var mouseDown = false;

   // Get drawing area coords
   function toDrawCoords(coords) {
    return {
     x: coords.clientX - paperOffset.left,
     y: coords.clientY - paperOffset.top
    };
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
    // Get area offset
    paperOffset = $("#paper").offset();
    paperOffset.left = Math.round(paperOffset.left);
    paperOffset.top = Math.round(paperOffset.top);
    // Init area
    var paper = Raphael("paper", 620, 420);
    // Create draw area
    var drawArea = paper.rect(0, 0, 619, 419, 10)
    drawArea.attr({fill: "#666"});

    // EVENTS
    drawArea.mousedown(function (event) {
     mouseDown = true;
     start = toDrawCoords(event);
     $("#startCoords").text("Start coords: " + $.dump(start));
    });
    drawArea.mouseup(function (event) {
     mouseDown = false;
     end = toDrawCoords(event);
     $("#endCoords").text("End coords: " + $.dump(end));
     buildJSON(paper);
    });
    drawArea.mousemove(function (event) {
     coords = toDrawCoords(event);
     $("#paperCoords").text("Paper coords: " + $.dump(coords));
     // if down and we've at least moved min percentage requirments
     if (mouseDown) {
      var xMovement = Math.abs(start.x - coords.x);
      var yMovement = Math.abs(start.y - coords.y);
      if (xMovement > X_MOVE || yMovement > Y_MOVE) {
       paper.path("M{0} {1}L{2} {3}", start.x, start.y, coords.x, coords.y);
       start = coords; 
      }
     }
    });


   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Douglas-Peucker algorithm to simplify your line.

I don't know of any javascript implementation (though googling directed me to forums for google maps developers) but here's a tcl implementation that is easy enough to understand: http://wiki.tcl.tk/27610

And here's a wikipedia article explaining the algorithm (along with pseudocode): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: This looks interesting. I imagine this will make my curves look more segmented however.

Comment: The algorithm has a tunable error value which you can use to decide how closely you want the resulting line to resemble the original line. The wikipedia article of course exaggerates a bit in its diagrams to illustrate how the algorithm works. Basically anytime you reduce the number of points in a line you are making the line more "segmented". Just like how games use low polygon 3D objects to improve speed. Same principle here but in 2D.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a drawing tool which works with the iPhone or the mouse
http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/drawtool2.php
However also look at Daves "game utility" @
http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/raphaelsource.php which generates path data as you draw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar. I found a way to incrementally add path commands by a little bypass of the Raphael API as outlined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885120/176841). In the modern browsers I tested on, this performs reasonably well but the degree to which your lines appear smooth depends on how fast the mousemove handler can work.

You might try my method for drawing paths using line segments and then perform smoothing after the initial jagged path is drawn (or as you go somehow), by pruning the coordinates using  Ramer–Douglas–Peucker as slebetman suggested, and converting the remaining `L`s to SVG curve commands.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simillar problem , I draw using the mouse down and the M command. I then save that path to a database on the server. The issue I am having is to do with resolution. I have a background image where the users draw lines and shapes over parts of the image, but if the image is displayed on one resolution and the paths are created in that resolution then reopened on a different perhaps lower resolution, my paths get shifted and are not sized correctly. I guess what I am asking is : is there a way to draw a path over an image and make sure  no matter the size of the underlying image the path remains proprtionally correct.

Comment: This seems to be a longer discussion valid for a new SO-question. It's been quite some time but I believe this behaviour is set on the svg-canvas directly.
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html